# "Command Failed" while trying to convert Word documents to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, office-interop

I have written a function that converts Word documents to PDF. The code works perfectly fine for converting doc and docx files to PDF. However for certain word documents, the application throws an exception  "Command Failed".

For one of the files that was producing this error, I tried modifying the existing settings of the file by navigating to File > Help > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > File Block Settings but it didn't work.

I am using the below code for conversion:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            //Opening the Word document that is temporarily created
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(tempPath);
            // VERY IMPORTANT: do this to close the MS Word instance
            doc.SaveAs(pdfFilePath, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)doc).Close();
            ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)app).Quit();
            //Additional code to close Word Document and release resources after opening
            if (app != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            if (doc != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
```

"tempPath" is location of the word document and "pdfFilepath" is the location where the pdf document is to be saved.

Comment: So if you open one of the "broken" documents in Word yourself and manually save as a PDF does it work?

Comment: @Equalsk Yes it does.